# How can I bulk add user accounts to a GCP project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have 30 accounts I need to add to a project. I add the users to the org group, but when I try to add them on the project, there's no option to add a group (there's an option to add Google group, but I think that's a different thing)

Is there a way to add them all without me adding the users one by one?

Comment: Google Cloud Platform uses Google Groups for group management.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comment you can add your users to a Google Group , there is an option to a[dd multiple users to a Group](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6191469?hl=en#) at the same time. From here you can just add the Group to IAM like any other user.

If you plan to give different IAM roles to each user then yes you would have to add each one manually